# jquery submit form on click event works only once

Tags: jquery, forms

i have an issue submitting a form.

first of all this is my form :

```
<div class="table">
    <form action="galerie" method="POST" id="gestGal">
        <div class="tableHead">
            <span>Selection</span>
            <span>Nom de la Galerie</span>
            <span>Description</span>
            <span>Action</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tableBody">
            <?php $b = $pdo->findAll(); foreach ($b as $k) : ?>
            <div class="tableBodyElem">
                <span>
                    <div class="checkContent">
                        <label for="elem">
                            <div class="boxes">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="elem_<?= $k->id;?>" name="check[]" value="<?= $k->id;?>"/>
                                <label for="elem_<?= $k->id;?>" value="<?= $k->id;?>"></label>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <span><?= $k->title;?></span>
                <span><?= $k->description;?></span>
                <span class="tableIcons">
                    <img src="path/to/modif.png" alt="modifier" class="modifImg" data="<?php  echo $k->id; ?>">
                    <img src="path/to/suppr.png" alt="supprimer" class="supprImg" data="<?php  echo $k->id; ?>">
                </span>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="tableFooter">

        <span class="inputSub">
            <input type="submit" name="suppr" id="suppr" value="suppprimer" class="subs">
            <input type="submit" name="modif" id="modif" value="modifier"  class="subs">
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

and this is the jquery part :

```
jQuery(function($)

    $(".subs").on('click',function(event) {
    var subId       = event.target.id;
    var parent      = $(this).parents("form");
    var elemChecked = parent.find('checkbox');
    var elemId      = [];
    parent.find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        elemId.push($(this).val());
    });  
    if (subId == 'suppr') {
         var action      = "path/to/php_file";
         if (elemId === null){elemId = "no element selected";}else{
            $(".ajax").fadeIn('fast');
            $("#ajax_content").load(action,{"check[]":elemId});
        }
    }else if (subId == 'modif') {
        var action      = "path/to/php_file";
        if (elemId === null){elemId = "no element selected";}else{
            $(".ajax").fadeIn('fast');
          $("#ajax_content").load(action,{"check[]":elemId});
        }
    };
    return false;
});
```

});

my issue is :

if i click on '#suppr', the load works fine.

then i cancel my choice to change or to modify the selected items then it won't work anymore.

i replaced :

```
if (subId == 'suppr') {
         var action      = "path/to/php_file";
         if (elemId === null){elemId = "no element selected";}else{
            $(".ajax").fadeIn('fast');
            $("#ajax_content").load(action,{"check[]":elemId});
        }
    }else if (subId == 'modif') {
        var action      = "path/to/php_file";
        if (elemId === null){elemId = "no element selected";}else{
            $(".ajax").fadeIn('fast');
          $("#ajax_content").load(action,{"check[]":elemId});
        }
    };
```

by :

```
if (subId == 'suppr') {
   console.log('suppr');
}else if (subId == 'modif') {
    console.log('modif');       
};
```

then i get every click that i make on the submits buttons.

So i came to think that the probleme is with the loading part.

i searched in stack and over the web and found some responses but i can't seem to understand why and how to overcome this.

must i use each or is there any way to reload my loaded page or is there any better way to do it ?

Any help and explaination are welcome.

Thank you very much.

**++++++++++++++EDIT++++++++++++++**

[Here goes the Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oups/hBegn/19/).

I changed the .load() by .append() same issue

Comment: Not 100% sure it's the cause of the problem, but a `form` can only contain 1 `submit` button. Change them to `type="button"` and see if the problem remains.

Comment: it can have 2 submit button (well it works fine using only php) but am going to try using button

Comment: have the same issue with the button type

Comment: It would be better to look at Jsfiddle...

Comment: @j809 here goes the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oups/hBegn/19/). Just change the .load() by .append() and have the same issue